# Detecting mobile devices

Tags: javascript, mobile, detection

I have a Javascript code where I detect if my site is viewed from a mobile device. Below is my code:

```
(function() {
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i)
            ) {
        isMobile = true;
    }
})();
```

Does this code cover all the possible cases or is there are chance that some devices can bypass this check?

Comment: You could use the code found here: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ (There are *a lot* more cases than the ones you've covered).

Comment: How many new mobile devices will be available in the next few years? Will you update your script for every new one that appears?

Comment: @Jacob make sure you mark an answer as accepted/correct

Comment: Your original script could be nicer using regexp "or" operator, which is the pipe character: ...match(/Android|webOS|iPhone|...

Answer (score 13):

This is the best I found so far:

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ and is is free.

For example jQuery:
1) download the file from the site above
2) full listing down under

```
/**
 * jQuery.browser.mobile (http://detectmobilebrowser.com/)
 *
 * jQuery.browser.mobile will be true if the browser is a mobile device
 *
 **/
(function(a){(jQuery.browser=jQuery.browser||{}).mobile=/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
```

3) use the following:

/**
 * jQuery.browser.mobile (http://detectmobilebrowser.com/)
 *
 * jQuery.browser.mobile will be true if the browser is a mobile device
 *
 **/

basically if you write an alert: `alert(jQuery.browser.mobile);` after the above code the popup will show true or false according to your mobile device.

Comment: @jacob have you tried any of the answers?

Comment: In that website I couldn't see the docs.

Comment: what docs are you referring to?

Comment: I downloaded the JS implementation of detectmobilebrowsers.com and just didn't figure out how to use it. But after a few minutes formatting the compressed file I understood the source and I modified it according to my needs.

Comment: It's OK for me, but I suppose the lack of documentation on detectmobilebrowsers.com will be a common issue for other peoples.

Comment: I found it easy to use.

Comment: @Floradu88, I'm glad you found it easy to use, but to make StackOverflow better I know future comers (like myself) would like details on how to use the library more readily available. Could you add that to your answer?

Comment: @kentcdodds check my update, I used only the code and the comments from the website above.

Comment: Also I have used only c#, javascript and jquery sources from the above website in my projects.

Comment: I don't really like detectmobilebrowser.com... It applies too many small string tests against too many different fields, and case-insensitively too... It will likely match something mistakenly.  For example, I tested when `navigator.userAgent` was "Googlebot-Mobile" and it worked, but after closer examination, it matched the "t\-mo" portion of the regexp, which really was intended to match "T-Mobile" from `navigator.vendor`.  NOT SAFE, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

1. Java based  Mobile (like Samsung BADA, etc)
2. MODU, is another that will by pass this script as that runs on 'Qualcomm's Brew operating system'

I have these two in knowledge, don't know if there are more..