# onclick and ontouchstart simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, css, touch

I have an `ontouchstart` event triggered on my mobile view, its linked to this:

```
function mobileLinksShow() {
    document.querySelector('.mobile-head-bar-links').classList.toggle('mobile-head-bar-links-transition');
}
```

On my device (iPhone 5) when I tap the button, it toggles it twice and so it extends then contracts. This is because of the onclick and ontouchstart firing at the same time. Removing the onclick solves the issue on mobile but now the desktop browser clearly doesnt work, is there a way to suppress onclick on mobile?

HTML:

```
<span class='mobile-head-bar-left' ontouchstart='mobileLinksShow()' onclick='mobileLinksShow()' ><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
```

CSS:

```
.mobile-head-bar-links {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #F76845;
    transition: .5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
}

.mobile-head-bar-links-transition {
    height: 7em;
}
```

NB. I don't want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 6):

Found a work around by testing the browser type and removing the onclick accordingly:

```
function removeMobileOnclick() {
    if(isMobile()) {
        document.querySelector('.mobile-head-bar-left').onclick  = '';
    }
}

function isMobile() {
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i)
            ) {
        return true;
    }
}
window.addEventListener('load', removeMobileOnclick);
```

This way you can have both `onclick` and `ontouchstart` not interfering

***isMobile function taken from [Detecting mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610433/detecting-mobile-devices) and the `webOS` part removed as this saw the desktop browser as mobile.***

Comment: Bad approach due to touch devices are not limited to mobiles (and were NOT in 2014 as well).

Answer (score 6):

I just came up with the idea to just memorize if `ontouchstart` was ever triggered. In this case we are on a device which supports it and want to ignore the `onclick` event. Since `ontouchstart` should always be triggered *before* `onclick`, I'm using this:

```html
<script> touchAvailable = false; </script>
<button ontouchstart="touchAvailable=true; myFunction();" onclick="if(!touchAvailable) myFunction();">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can bind a function to ontouchstart which calls whatever is bound to onclick, but then prevents default so that it doesn't actually also trigger onclick.

You can then easily copy paste this ontouchstart event to all places where you use onclick.

```
<span class='mobile-head-bar-left' ontouchstart='touch_start(event)' onclick='mobileLinksShow()' ><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>

<script>
function touch_start(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.onclick();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not working in Chrome v65: https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080

Comment: This solution worked for me, except it blocked the page from scrolling if the mobile user happened to have placed his/her thumb over the element. I found a better way to prevent the onclick event by placing it inside a child element and setting its CSS property pointer-events to "none" for the mobile version (using media queries).

Answer (score 1):

Place the onclick event inside a child element and set its `pointer-events` property to `none` for the mobile version. This will block all click events for the child element and allow touch events to occur without interference.

HTML:

```
<span class='mobile-head-bar-left' ontouchstart='mobileLinksShow()' ><span class='mobile-head-bar-left-click' onclick='mobileLinksShow()'><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span></span>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {

    .mobile-head-bar-left-click {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it this way:

```
var called = false;
function mobileLinksShow() {
    if(!called)
        document.querySelector('.mobile-head-bar-links').classList.toggle('mobile-head-bar-links-transition');
        called = true;
    }
}
```

**But:** If you use this code, the function can only be called once, even if you click the span twice.

Answer (score 0):

This is still broken for cases like a touchscreen laptop (where 'click' may be from touch or from a mouse). Its also broken in some mobile cases where click doesn't come from touch (eg. Enter key on an attached or bluetooth keyboard).

The right solution is to correctly mark the touch event as handled with preventDefault, then no click event will be generated.  Eg.

```
function mobileLinksShow(event) {
  document.querySelector('.mobile-head-bar-links').classList.toggle('mobile-head-bar-links-transition');
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

Using `e.preventDefault()` for touch events is not working by default [start from chrome 56](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080).

You can let it work manually by setting the [`{ passive: false }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) option:

```js
document.querySelector('mobile-head-bar-left')
  .addEventListener(
    'touchstart',
    function(e) {
      // do something
      e.preventDefault()
    },
    { passive: false }
  )
```